# How to read a boolean from database (use cursor)?

Tags: android, sqlite, cursor

Why can't I read bool type from cursor? I'm using this code:

```
private boolean readBooleanByKey(Cursor cursor, int key) {

    try {
        return cursor.getInt(key) > 0; // always return false 
    } catch (Exception e) {            
    }
}
```

*This is part of DDL from database table*

```
  CREATE TABLE [dn_user_cars] (
     [id] [INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT],   
     [archived] BOOLEAN; // this variable I cant read
```

Comment: Hard to tell, if we can't see how do you set the data in the table or what data is in it...

Comment: Why the `try`/`catch`?

Comment: I don't think there is a BOOLEAN data type in SQLite

Comment: alpinescrambler - you're right! Answer as the answer, and I will mention to you the right answer! Thank you very much!

Comment: there are no boolean data types in sqlite, `SQLite does not have a separate Boolean storage class. Instead, Boolean values are stored as integers 0 (false) and 1 (true).` from the [docs](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is a BOOLEAN data type in SQLite. See some docs here: http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html

Answer (score 3):

To store value you can user integer value:

```
int flag = (boolValue) ? 1 : 0;
```

to read value from integer "number" value to boolean:

```
boolean flag2 = (intValue == 1) ? true : false;
```